# Promise.all() fetches all requests at once and not one after one

Tags: node.js, promise, fetch

I am trying to have multiple fetches one after one and then process the results one by one. I tried doing as described in several other questions but somehow, my fetches are all started at once which fails my function.

```
let counter = 0;
let rounds = selectedTypes.length;

Promise.all(selectedTypes.map((type) => {
    let body = {
        selectedScreenshot: type,
        dataUrl: dataUrl
    };
    console.log(type);
    return fetch(URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    })
        .then((resp) => {
            counter++;
            var pleaseWait = document.getElementById('please-wait');
            pleaseWait.innerText = `Please wait - ${counter} of ${rounds} done!`;
            console.log(counter);
            return resp.text();
        }) // Transform the data into json
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log('data: ', data);
            console.log('next');
            return data;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
)).then(urls => {
    console.log('done', urls);
})
```

The "type" print out is done directly after I start the function for all selected types. However I want the type to be logged, then "data" and then "next" and then the second type. And when everything is finished it should print "done" and all the URLS.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Promise.all executes all async operations at once.
You could be interested in such operation: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

Comment: @ŽilvinasJocius she would be forced to use blue-bird promises package tho, this is not part of native JS promises afaik.

Comment: `Promise.all` never was described as doing things sequentially anywhere? The `map` loop you're using does all the requests at once. The `Promise.all` then only waits for all the results, nothing more.

Comment: @ŽilvinasJocius `Promise.all`  does not `executes all async operations at once`, it waits for all _"async operations"_ (Promises), that are already running and passed to `Promise.all` as a list, to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for .. of along with async/await to await for each call to complete before moving on to the next one..

For example:

```js
const URL = 'https://httpbin.org/post';
const dataUrl = 'dataUrl';
const selectedTypes = [...Array(10).keys()].map(n => `type${n}`);
let counter = 0;
let rounds = selectedTypes.length;

function delay(delayMs) {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayMs));
}

async function postData() {

    let result = [];
    for (let type of selectedTypes) {
        let body = {
            selectedScreenshot: type,
            dataUrl: dataUrl
        };
        console.log(type);

        try {
            console.info(`Making fetch call #${(counter||0)+1} of ${selectedTypes.length}`);
            const resp = await fetch(URL, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
                credentials: 'same-origin',
            });

            // Get the text data (JSON)
            const data = await resp.text();
            counter++;
            var pleaseWait = document.getElementById('please-wait');
            pleaseWait.innerText = `Please wait - ${counter} of ${rounds} done!`;
            console.log(counter);   
            result.push(data);
            // Only adding this in to slow demo down.. we can remove in production.
            await delay(1000);
        } catch (err) {
            console.err('An error has occurred:', err);
            throw err;
        }
    }

    console.log("done:", result);
}

// If any request fails the error will bubble up to here (as a result of re-throwing the error in the catch block. If we omitted the try/catch we'd get much the same behaviour.
postData().catch(err => console.log("Top level error:", err));
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="test-fetch-foreach.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="please-wait"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but this solution ignores the idea of Promise.all- if one promise rejects all promises should reject. I guess thats what the OP wanted when he used promise.all(), thats usually why you use it in the first place.

Comment: That's an excellent point @Gibor, Promise.all will reject if any of the calls fail. However we can use a try/catch with async / await to exit the function early if any of the fetch calls fail. I will update the answer to provide this behaviour.

Comment: We can also use a .catch() on the postData function to catch any unhandled error.

Comment: @Gibor a loop with `await` will throw (and cause the surrounding promise to reject) when any of the awaited promises fail as well, not sure where you're seeing a difference? (Actually the OPs code is sprinkled with `.catch(err => console.log(err))` that ignore any errors, so it never fails - to replicate that one would need to `try`/`catch` without rethrowing).

Comment: haha yeah thats what I was about to ask, why not try-catch the whole thing. I guess its just an approach difference, unless you want the log to give details on the exact promise which failed, then your solution is better.

Comment: If one wished to carry regardless of the fetch one could swallow the err in the catch block and keep on going. It depends on the context, if you were updating financial data you would probably stop after any error (I hope!!), however if you were doing some web scraping you might well drop any error (though you'd likely log them)

Comment: unfortunately I can't go with async/await as I have class methods which can't(?) be async?

Comment: @threxx why not?

Comment: can I? When I add it to my method (async function selectTypes() {..}) I get "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected"

Comment: You can mark a class method as async, e.g. class myClass { async method1() {} }. It does depend on your Browser, or the version of Node.js you are using. There's a compatibility list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @threxx a method definition doesn't use the `function` keyword

Comment: You should be fine with Node.js 7.6 or later or any modern Browser.. not Internet Explorer though..